# Azure - How many users can a webservice role support?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, azure

I saw this question:

[How many users on one azure instance before I hit performance issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528698/how-many-users-on-one-azure-instance-before-i-hit-performance-issues)

Which discusses how many users an azure instance could support for a webpage. I'm wondering if this would be any different for a webpage vs webserver that client applications (such as mobile phones) are call into, to get data. For example, if you have a single azure webrole running that exposes a REST enpoint, how many devices could call into the service before it starts to buckle under pressure?

Answer (score 5):

How long is a string? :-)

If your app computes one million digits of pi on each web request, it will probably handle fewer concurrent web requests than an app that replies to each web request with "hello world."

(This is another, blunter, version of David's answer.)

Comment: +1 just for making me laugh out loud. And I'm now going to plagiarize (er, use) that in my scalability talks.

Comment: Glad you liked it. :-) "How long is a string?" isn't my line. I heard it years ago in response to similar load/scale questions. I have no idea who originated it.

Answer (score 3):

A Web Role instance is merely a Windows 2008 Server R2 (or SP2) virtual machine of a given size (1-8 cores, 1.75-14GB usable RAM, 100-800Mbps network). You can run web sites, different web servers (tomcat, for example), WCF services (through IIS or standalone ServiceHosts), etc.

Scaling is going to depend heavily on the app itself: Is it CPU-constrained? Network-constrained? Do you have queue-based workload and your queue backlog is growing?

Sometimes it's critical to scale *up* to larger VMs, just to handle one of the constraints mentioned. It's always wise to pick the smallest VM size to run in a baseline mode (e.g. 1 or 2 users), then scale *out* to more instances as needed.

It's important to identify the key performance indicators (KPI's) for your app. You can then automate  your scaling, with something like the [Autoscale Appliction Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680892%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) (WASABi).

Here's a [reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee814754.aspx) with all VM sizes, with details about CPU, local disk, network bandwidth, and RAM.